# Counter Example: Span Inclusion

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

For any two subsets $S$ and $S'$ of a vector space $V$ does $span(S) \cap span(S') = span(S \cap S')$?

---

If $S=ax, a \in \mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S'=by, b \in \mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then the intersection of their spans should be what?

Comment: That "Also" has nothing to do with the first question, and therefore does not belong here. Open a new question (or look in any book on linear algebra, this is the exchange lemma).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Could you help me understand my ALSO question?

Comment: Let $S$ be a nonempty linearly independent subset of a vector space $V$. Then for any nonzero vector $v \in V$, there is a vector $x \in S$ such that the set $(S $\ $\{x\}) \cup \{v\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: What is $(S$ \ $\{x\}) \cup \{v\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $S=\{a\}$ and $S'=\{-a\}$ with $a \neq -a$.

Comment: What is $a$? Please be more specific.

Comment: Any vector with $a \neq -a$.

Answer (score 0):

Is the second question a hint provided by your instructor? It already answers your first question: Let $a,b$ be two distinct scalars and $x$ be a nonzero vector. Let $S=\{ax\}$ and $S'=\{bx\}$ (note: $S$ and $S'$ are singletons). Then $\operatorname{span}(S)=\operatorname{span}(S')=\operatorname{span}(\{x\})$ and hence $\operatorname{span}(S)\cap\operatorname{span}(S')=\operatorname{span}(\{x\})$, which is one-dimensional, but $\operatorname{span}(S\cap S')=\operatorname{span}(\phi)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the vectorspace $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ over the field $F=\mathbb{R}$.

Let $S=\{(1,0)\}, S'=\{(2,0)\}$, then $S\cap S'=\{\}$, empty set,
So, $span(S\cap S')=\{\}$, empty set.

But, $span(S)=\{\alpha(1,0): \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}=\{(\alpha,0): \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is real-axis, $span(S')=\{2(\beta,0): \beta \in \mathbb{R}\}=\{(2\beta,0): \beta \in \mathbb{R}\}=\{(a,0): a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is again real-axis.

Thus $span(S)\cap span(S')$ is entire real axis.

Therefore,

$Span(S\cap S') \ne span(S)\cap span(S')$

Keys:

1. $A\cap B = \{x: x\in A ~\text{and}~ x \in B\}$
2. Span(S) = collection of all (finite) linear combination elements of $S$, i.e, $span(S)= \{ \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_iv_i: \alpha_i \in F\}$, where $S=\{v_1,v_2,..v_k\}$.
3. For any non-empty set $S$  of a vectorspace $V$ over $F$, $span(S)$ is always subspace of $V$